# ITelemetryProcessor doesn't work when adding properties from HttpContext session data

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights, httpcontext, httpsession, telemetry

For the following code, GetSessionData will return deserialized data (dictionary) stored earlier (in a middleware) to the HttpContext.Session payload. However I tried, I don't see the items get ingested to the request log on Application Insights for any http requests shot from browser.

```
public void Process(ITelemetry tel)
{
    if (tel is ISupportProperties sp)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> items = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.GetSessionData();
        if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in items)
            {
                sp.Properties[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    this._next.Process(tel);
}
```

But for the following code, I could always see it in customDimensions of each request.

```
public void Process(ITelemetry tel)
{
    if (tel is ISupportProperties sp)
    {
        sp.Properties["MyTestKey"] = "MyTestValue";
    }

    this._next.Process(tel);
}
```

Any reason why?

Comment: Can you make sure the items is not empty? You can set a checkpoint in `Process` method to see if the code(like `sp.Properties[entry.Key] = entry.Value;`) is actually executed.

Comment: Normally I would expect that properties are added using a [`ITelemetryInitializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) implementation, not a TelemetryProcessor. Not sure if it does help for this case. If you create a class derived from `TelemetryInitializerBase` you get a method `protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(HttpContext platformContext, RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, ITelemetry telemetry)` to implement which gives access to the http context.